# cx_Oracle Connection Pool

Tags: python, oracle, transaction, pool

Нужно сделать Connection Pool c использованием cx_Oracle.

Нужно иметь возможность выполнить несколько запросов к базе данных 
в рамках одной транзакции, при том что запросы могут выполняться из разных процессов.
То есть один процесс создал соединение выполнил пару запросов, осободил соединение, после чего другой процесс подключается к тому же соединению и выполняет другие запросы в рамках той же транзакции.

Сначала попробовал использовать DRCP как описано тут:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dsl/python-091105.html

Но данные транзакции между соеднинениями не сохраняются:

В качестве проверки использую следующий код:

```
#coding: utf-8

import cx_Oracle

con1 = cx_Oracle.connect('user/pass:127.0.0.1:1521/XE:POOLED', cclass='test', purity=cx_Oracle.ATTR_PURITY_NEW)
cur = con1.cursor()
cur.execute('''insert into gui_view (id, name, view_type, title) values (gui_view_s.nextVal, 'TEST_VIEW', 'grid', 'VIEW_TITLE') ''')
cur1 = con1.cursor()
cur1.execute('''select id from gui_view where title = 'VIEW_TITLE' ''')
rows_all1 = cur1.fetchall()
assert len(rows_all1) > 0, 'Not Exists!'
con1.close()

con2 = cx_Oracle.connect('user/pass:127.0.0.1:1521/XE:POOLED', cclass='test1', purity=cx_Oracle.ATTR_PURITY_SELF)
cur2 = con2.cursor()
cur2.execute('''select id from gui_view where title = 'VIEW_TITLE' ''')
rows_all = cur2.fetchall()
assert len(rows_all) == 0, 'Exist!'

con3 = cx_Oracle.connect('user/pass:127.0.0.1:1521/XE:POOLED', cclass='test')
cur3 = con3.cursor()
cur3.execute('''select id from gui_view where title = 'VIEW_TITLE' ''')
rows_all3 = cur3.fetchall()
con3.close()

assert len(rows_all3) > 0, 'Not Exists!'
```

Третье условие не проходит.
Возможно я не правильно использую параметры и как-то можно получить одно и тоже соединение ?

Есть идея сделать отдельный процесс в котором создавать соединение и через сокет общаться с основным приложением реализовав таким образом постоянное соединение (видимо что-то наподобие sqlrelay).

Может быть уже есть какая-то легкая открытая реализация для данной задачи, чтобы не писать самому ?

Вот еще одна ссылка:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28395/oci09adv.htm#LNOCI87720

Тут говорится, что соединения с сохранением состояния могут быть реализованы через connection pool, а без сохранения состояния через session pool.
То есть по идее в Oracle должна быть такая возможность.

Да и если подумать (возможно мое представление ошибочно) у сервиса базы данных запущены процессы с соедиенениями, нужно только как-то подключиться к одному и тому же.

Comment: Connection Pool - это совсем другое. Я сам не пробовал, только краем уха слышал, что пакет [DBMS_XA](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_xa.htm#ARPLS209) делает то, что вам нужно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо @Dmitry и http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_packages_dbms_xa.htm получилось сделать такой вариант:

```
#coding: utf-8

import cx_Oracle

req_start = '''
declare
  v_my_transaction  pls_integer;
  v_xa_xid     dbms_xa_xid := dbms_xa_xid(3322);
  v_xa_exception exception;
  v_ora_error pls_integer;
begin

  v_my_transaction  := dbms_xa.xa_start(
                        xid => v_xa_xid,
                        flag =>  dbms_xa.tmnoflags);

--Check if XA transaction is OK
  if v_my_transaction <> dbms_xa.xa_ok then
    v_ora_error := dbms_xa.xa_getlastoer();
    rabus_utl.debug_db('Attention! Oracle Error - ORA-' || v_ora_error || ' obtained. XA Process failed!');
    raise v_xa_exception;
  else dbms_output.put_line(a => 'XA Process ID 3322 started');
  end if;

end;
'''

req_start_continue = '''
declare
  v_my_transaction  pls_integer;
  v_xa_xid     dbms_xa_xid := dbms_xa_xid(3322);
  v_xa_exception exception;
  v_ora_error pls_integer;
begin

  v_my_transaction  := dbms_xa.xa_start(
                        xid => v_xa_xid,
                        flag =>  dbms_xa.tmresume);

--Check if XA transaction is OK
  if v_my_transaction <> dbms_xa.xa_ok then
    v_ora_error := dbms_xa.xa_getlastoer();
    rabus_utl.debug_db('Attention! Oracle Error - ORA-' || v_ora_error || ' obtained. XA Process failed!');
    raise v_xa_exception;
  else dbms_output.put_line(a => 'XA Process ID 3322 started');
  end if;

end;
'''

req_end = '''
declare
  v_my_transaction  pls_integer;
  v_xa_xid     dbms_xa_xid := dbms_xa_xid(3322);
  v_xa_exception exception;
  v_ora_error pls_integer;
begin

  v_my_transaction  := dbms_xa.xa_end(
                        xid => v_xa_xid,
                        flag =>  dbms_xa.tmsuspend);

 if v_my_transaction <> dbms_xa.xa_ok then
    v_ora_error := dbms_xa.xa_getlastoer();
   rabus_utl.debug_db('Attention! Oracle Error - ORA-' || v_ora_error || ' obtained. XA Process failed!');
    raise v_xa_exception;
   else dbms_output.put_line(a => 'XA Process ID 3322 is working!');
  end if;
end;

'''

req_end_rollback = '''
declare
  v_my_transaction  pls_integer;
  v_xa_xid     dbms_xa_xid := dbms_xa_xid(3322);
  v_xa_exception exception;
  v_ora_error pls_integer;
begin

  v_my_transaction  := dbms_xa.xa_end(
                        xid => v_xa_xid,
                        flag =>  dbms_xa.tmsuspend);

 v_my_transaction := dbms_xa.xa_rollback(
                             xid => v_xa_xid);

 if v_my_transaction <> dbms_xa.xa_ok then
    v_ora_error := dbms_xa.xa_getlastoer();
   rabus_utl.debug_db('Attention! Oracle Error - ORA-' || v_ora_error || ' obtained. XA Process failed!');
    raise v_xa_exception;
   else dbms_output.put_line(a => 'XA Process ID 3322 is working!');
  end if;
end;

'''

con1 = cx_Oracle.connect('user/pass:127.0.0.1:1521/XE:POOLED', cclass='test', purity=cx_Oracle.ATTR_PURITY_NEW)
cur = con1.cursor()
cur.execute(req_start)
cur.execute('''insert into gui_view (id, name, view_type, title) values (gui_view_s.nextVal, 'TEST_VIEW', 'grid', 'VIEW_TITLE') ''')

cur1 = con1.cursor()
cur1.execute('''select id from gui_view where title = 'VIEW_TITLE' ''')
rows_all1 = cur1.fetchall()
assert len(rows_all1) > 0, 'Not Exists!'

cur.execute(req_end)
con1.close()

con2 = cx_Oracle.connect('user/pass:127.0.0.1:1521/XE:POOLED', cclass='test1', purity=cx_Oracle.ATTR_PURITY_SELF)
cur2 = con2.cursor()
cur2.execute('''select id from gui_view where title = 'VIEW_TITLE' ''')
rows_all = cur2.fetchall()
assert len(rows_all) == 0, 'Exist!'

con3 = cx_Oracle.connect('user/pass:127.0.0.1:1521/XE:POOLED', cclass='test')
cur3 = con3.cursor()
cur3.execute(req_start_continue)
cur3.execute('''select id from gui_view where title = 'VIEW_TITLE' ''')
rows_all3 = cur3.fetchall()
cur3.execute(req_end_rollback)
con3.close()

assert len(rows_all3) > 0, 'Not Exists!'
```

Который работает.